# How to select color from the given image for Storyboard?

Tags: ios, colors, storyboard

Our UI give me a image, which have the app main color.

[image]

And I use the color meter to select the color:

[image]

But, after I set the color to the storyboard (hint color), and run it in simulator, I get the different between them:

Left is UI given image, right is simulator, why there is so big difference here? How can I avoid it?

[image]

Comment: set navigation bar to Opaque, currently its translucent

Comment: @Mr.Bista Thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your navigationBar is set to translucent. You can change it as in this image [image]
That should be it. Happy Coding.